# Intent shows a blank image

Tags: android, android-intent

When i try to open an image on the gallery (I'm developing a file manager) using intent, the image shown is totally black., but I can't understand why, as I've also followed the last best practices by google about getting the Uri (with FileProvider).

MainActivity.java

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    Uri uri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",image);
                    intent.setDataAndType(uri,MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileName));
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>

</paths>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

to:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

as right now, the other app has no rights to view the image identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: not sure why it should show Image as black? instead should have thrown some form of exception IMHO

Comment: @AADTechnical: The exception would have been in the other app, not the OP's app.

Comment: Dude, you saved me some hectic searching. Thanks for the answer!